# IIS can't serve WebAssembly module

Tags: pdf, iis, webassembly, pspdfkit

I'm using PSPDFKit SDK and I'm trying to load it within my page. It loads just fine locally, but when it comes to stage I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Error loading https://***.com/mcclubone/_ATF/Inc/PSPDFKit/pspdfkit-lib/pspdfkit-bb2d75a643cc7546.wasm: Not Found at 500d608b-a6cc-4154-b84a-5d35a6e80ca9:12:135914".
```

It looks like stage's IIS can't serve WebAssembly modules, but I did add that 'application/wasm' type to MIME types in IIS config what should make it work and it doesn't happen. I've compared both (local and stage) environments and their confings are the same. The only difference is that locally I'm using IIS for Windows 10 and on stage it's IIS for Windows Server 2012.

I think this issue is related to serving .wasm files and not specifically to PSPDFKit.

Can anybody suggest something to solve that painful problem?

Comment: While it says "not found", you might hit another 404.x error instead of 404.0. Please open IIS log files and learn the sub status code, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code

Comment: Same thread: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71734730/iis-cant-serve-webassembly-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71734730/iis-cant-serve-webassembly-module).

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved. Due to the fact that we have a complex network hierarchy and structure, the folder was copied incorrectly, hence IIS couldn't find the file that was being requested.